# Accessing constructors variables in node. js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning node.js

I have a class like this ->

```
 const client = require('prom-client');

class PrometheusController {
    constructor () {
        let counter = new client.Counter({ name: 'http_total_requests', namespace:"test", help: 'test' });
}

    get (fn) {
        this.counter.inc(); // Inc with 1
}
```

Node js complains that the counter is undefined.

I tried saving the `this` variable as the posts here recommend but that is not accessible either - [javascript class variable scope in callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317724/javascript-class-variable-scope-in-callback-function)

How do I access the constructors variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot. Variables declared inside the `constructor` can only be accessed from the constructor.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
constructor() {
    this.counter = new client.Counter(...);
}
```

---

Remember, ES6 Classes are merely syntactic sugar around constructor functions so the above code corresponds to this ES5 code:

```
function PrometheusController() {
    this.counter = new client.Counter(...);
}
```

which can be used like:

```
let controller = new PrometheusController();
// controller.counter can be used here
```