# Variable Scope in Callback function in Class

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317724/javascript-class-variable-scope-in-callback-function) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80084/in-javascript-why-is-the-this-operator-inconsistent) question. Both handle the variable scope in functions and not in classes where I can not make the *that* trick. How can I set a class variable in the callback method?

```
class A{
constructor(){
  this.name="";
}
callbackFunction(){
  this.name="abc"; //not working, this is undefined
}

loadComponents(){
 promise.then(this.callbackFunction);
}
}
```

Comment: Use `() => this.callbackFunction()` or `.bind`