# Object.create to create an object with costructor

Tags: javascript, oop

I am learning Javascript and I am a C++ programmer. I have tried creating an object with a constructor with object.create and here is the result:

```
var PlayGround ={
    initGrid : function(N) {
        this.N=N;

        this.grid = new Array(N);
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            this.grid[i] = new Array(N);
            for (var j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                this.grid[i][j] = false;
            }


        }
        return true;

}
};

var PlayGround_property = {
    N:{
        value: 100,
        writable:true
    },
    grid:{
        value:null,
        writable:true
    }

}

var board= Object.create(PlayGround, PlayGround_property);
```

It works as I want: the object board contains the object grid, and now I can use the set and get keyword to define the behaviour of the = and () operator.
Anyway I have read around the web that the

> this

keyword in Javascript is not safe and I want to be sure that it is referring always to the board object and not to the global window object. Is there a way or I am overthinking?
Other question, are there other ways to write object with a constructor (and maybe other members) in Javascript?

Comment: When you are inside an object, the `this` keyword always refers to the object and not the window. However, nested inside these objects could be objects that also use this to refer to themselves. You can't go back up the scope, so you'll have to declare a `var self = this;` Otherwise you can be pretty sure `this` refers to the object you are in.

Comment: @somethinghere—"*When you are inside an object, the this keyword always refers to the objec*" is not correct. The *this* keyword is a feature of *functions*, and is set by how the function is called.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that "*the `this` keyword in Javascript is not safe*"? It is entirely under your control.

Comment: @RobG Yes, the `this` keyword only applies to functions' scope, but it does refer to the object, otherwise the following would't work: `var a = {b  : function(){ alert(this.c); }, c : "log"}; a.b();`

Comment: @RobG from http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html . I have to admit that I do not understood everything about that article. So my could be just an impression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80084/in-javascript-why-is-the-this-operator-inconsistent/80127#80127 this answer is the most comprensible for me

Comment: @somethinghere—how about `var x = a.b; x()` or `a.b.bind(window); a.b()` or `element.onclick = a.b` or … ;-)

Comment: @RobG Thats what they invented the word _'goshdarnit'_ for. :)

Comment: @BiA—that answer is correct within a limited context, it's incomplete and doesn't fully cover the topic. Try [*MDN this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be sure that [this] is referring always to the board object

A function's *this* is set either by how you call the function, or *bind*. So just make sure you call methods the right way. If you always call functions as methods of *board*, then *this* within the methods will always reference *board*.

If you are only going to have one instance of *board*, there doesn't seem much point in using a constructor. If you have multiple instances of *board*, then you want *this* to reference the particular instance that called the method so you don't want to fix *this* using *bind*.

Crockford just doesn't like the use of *new*, so encouraged *Object.create*, it fits his idea of how inheritance should work.

Your pattern could be rewritten to use a constructor something like:

```
function PlayGround (N) {
    this.N = N;
    this.grid = []; // Use array literal, it's less to type

    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        this.grid[i] = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            this.grid[i][j] = false; // Not sure why you bother with this
        }
    }
}

var board = new Playground(100);
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but that should be close. Note that javascipt is loosely typed, so only initialise variables and properties if you have something useful to assign. Variables are created with a value of *undefined*, Array properties are only created if you actually assign something to them, creating an array with length N does not create any indexes, e.g.

```
var arr = new Array(10);
console.log(arr.length); // 10
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty(0)); // false
```