# Why can't I call router.get after passing it this way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, this

I have a node/express server

```
//I'm using these
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
applyRouter = function(rget){
    rget('/something', function(req,res,next){
        console.log("anything");
    });
}
applyRouter(router.get);
```

And I get this error

```
path/to/express/lib/router/index.js:509
    var route = this.route(path)
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined
```

[Well OK](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L509), here's line 509

```
// create Router#VERB functions
methods.concat('all').forEach(function(method){
  proto[method] = function(path){
    var route = this.route(path)
    route[method].apply(route, slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return this;
  };
});
```

What does `this` refer to here?

I tried

```
var outerThis = this;
applyRouter = function(rget){
    console.log("inside", this);
    rget.apply(outerThis, ['/something', function(req,res,next){
        console.log("anything");
    }]);
}
applyRouter(router.get);
```

and

```
console.log("outside", this); //gives {}
applyRouter = function(rget){
    console.log("inside", this);
    rget.apply({}, ['/something', function(req,res,next){
        console.log("anything");
    }]);
}
applyRouter(router.get);
```

Same error... what's going on? Why can't I do this?

I can do

```
applyRouter = function(router){
    router.get('/something', function(req,res,next){
        console.log("anything");
    });
}
applyRouter(router);
```

So I'm setting `this` wrongly. What does `router` expect `this` to be? Where specifically does `this` get changed?

Comment: why aren't you using router as shown on express documentation?

Comment: I was experimenting and I'm interested in this specific behavior

Comment: There are great questions/answers that cover all the details of how `this` works.. nothing new or node/express specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80084/in-javascript-why-is-the-this-operator-inconsistent

Comment: `applyRouter(router.get.bind(null, router));`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of null`

Comment: Thank you @MedetTleukabiluly , the problem was resolved using `rget.bind(router)('/something', func...` when it is called. How come `rget.apply(...)` was not working though?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Oh, because `this` should be `router`. Whoops