# How to use object methods as callbacks to modify object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, request

I am building an interface to a REST API, and in the process of using the javascript [request](https://github.com/request/request) module, I found trouble trying to return values from the callback.  Request does not work that way, and you must handle the data from within the callback.

But I need to process and compare data from many requests, so I decided to push the data to some database object from within my callback.

I made an prototype function to be called as the callback to keep the data structure modular.

I am baffled because when I try to modify this.value from within my callback function, the result does not go to the proper place.

I expect the callback function to modify my instance of the database, and to be able to access that change later on after waiting for the callback to finish.
In the code sample below, I show that I am I am able to do exactly this with globalString, but in globalDatabase, the assignment does not survive past the end of the callback function.

I suspect I may be using my object pointers incorrectly.  can anyone point out the flaw in how I modify this.value, or provide a good alternative to the way I am using OOP here.

A good solution should be able to assign a value from inside the callback and then access that value from another function which is not called by the callback.

What is the best way to store the data from my callback?

```
    var Database = function(){
        console.log("<Executing constructor>");
        this.value = "initial constructor data";
    };
    Database.prototype.myCallback = function(error, response, body){
        console.log("<Executing callback>");
        this.value = body;
        globalString = body;
    };
    globalString = "blank";
    globalDatabase = new Database();
    console.log(globalString, "|" ,globalDatabase.value);
    main();
    function main(){
        var request = require('request');
        requestParams = {
            url: "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
            method: "GET",
            json: true
        };
        request(requestParams, globalDatabase.myCallback);
        console.log(globalString, "|" ,globalDatabase.value);
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(globalString, "|" ,globalDatabase.value);
        }, 2 * 1000);//seconds wait time for callback to finish
    };
```

I was able to replicate this problem using callbacks in setTimeout.

```js
var Database = function(){
    console.log("<Executing constructor>");
    this.value = "initial constructor data";
};
Database.prototype.myCallback = function(){
    console.log("<Executing callback>");
    this.value = "callback modified data";
};
d = new Database();//global target for async modification
main();
function main(){
    console.log("First, the object contains: ",d.value);
    setTimeout(d.myCallback, 1 * 1000);//seconds wait time
    console.log("Back in main, the object contains: ", d.value);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("After waiting patiently, the object contains: ",d.value);
    }, 2 * 1000);//seconds wait time
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-known "quirk" of Javascript: when you call your `myCallback` function from the `request` function (or from `setTimeout`), the *context* of the call is the `request` function - this means that `this` refers to `request`, **not** to your `Database` object. So, for example, if you call `myCallback` from a DOM event handler, then `this` will refer to the DOM element.

There are a number of good answers explaining this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025839/2008384) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80127/2008384).

Now, for a solution to your specific problem, here's a code sample. I took the liberty of rewriting your second example using ES6 classes, since I think it's a little clearer that way:

```js
class Database {
  constructor() {
    console.log('<Executing constructor>');
    this.value = 'initial constructor data';

    // bind `this` to the `myCallback` function so that whenever we call 
    // `myCallback`, it will always have the correct `this`
    // 
    this.myCallback = this.myCallback.bind(this);
  }

  myCallback() {
    console.log('<Executing callback>');
    this.value = 'callback modified data';
  }
}


let d = new Database(); //global target for async modification

main();
function main(){
  console.log("First, the object contains: ",d.value);
  setTimeout(d.myCallback, 1 * 1000);//seconds wait time
  console.log("Back in main, the object contains: ", d.value);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("After waiting patiently, the object contains: ",d.value);
  }, 2 * 1000);//seconds wait time
};
```

Notice the call the `bind` in the constructor. That "replaces" the `myCallback` method with a new version of the same method where the context is always the `this` that refers to the class.