# Access current element's 'this' object when an external 'this' was bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype

Don't know if the question's title is too confusing but here I go.

If I got something like:

```
var Test = function(){
    this.foo = a;
}

Test.prototype.init = function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.form-control', this.myFunction);
}

Test.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
    console.log(this);
}
```

My understanding is that when printing '*this*' in myFunction it would print the execution context of the function that made the call, in this case it'll print the execution context for *.on('change' ...)*. So when printing *this.foo* since it doesn't exist in that context then **undefined** will be printed out.

To solve this issue and to access *this.foo*, I'm doing the following:

```
Test.prototype.init = function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.form-control', (this.myFunction).bind(this));
}

Test.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
    console.log(this);
}
```

I'm binding '*this*' to the function call, so *this.foo* would be printed out which is OK, but my question is, in that case how can I also get access to the execution context for *.on('change' ...)*??? Meaning, how can I access the '*this*' that I had originally access to before the binding?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80084/in-javascript-why-is-the-this-operator-inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding, just use a reference variable. It will maintain the context, and still allow you to use the `.on`'s context with `this`

```
Test.prototype.init = function () {

    var context = this;

    $(document).on('change', '.form-control', function () {
        context.myFunction();
        console.log(this); // `this` has context to the onchange
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A bound function's `this` will always be bound to that same value. That means you no longer have access to the "original" value.

If you want to use both `this`es, you'll have to use one as `this` and the other as an argument. Or both as arguments.

```js
var Test = function(a) {
  this.foo = a;
  this.init();
}

Test.prototype.init = function() {
  // Set `this` to the calling test object, and window
  // (which would be the original context in this case)
  // as first parameter of `myFunction`. Swap the arguments
  // if you wish to use them the other way around.
  window.setTimeout(this.myFunction.bind(this, window), 500);
};

Test.prototype.myFunction = function(that) {
  console.log(this.foo);
  console.log(that.foo);
};

new Test(5);
```

Btw, ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) keep the environment they're defined in, meaning that `this` would point to your test object.

```
Test.prototype.init = function() {
  window.setTimeout(() => this.myFunction(window), 500);
};
```