# Weird behavior of bound function

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

Can someone explaind what is happening here?

```
var dog = {
   name: "Dogo"
}

var echo = function() {
    console.log(this);
}

dog.echo = echo.bind(this);

echo();
dog.echo();
```

The first `echo()` prints out the global object as expected.
However the second one prints empty object `{}` isntead of what the first `echo()` printed. Why?

Edit: Sorry! I didn't mention that the code is run by nodejs interpreter!

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can’t reproduce that. Are you running in Node? `this` isn’t the global object in module scope there, so when you call `echo.bind(this)` you’re binding a different object.

Comment: Where is this code executed?

Comment: In console both the thing are printing window object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Javascript, why is the "this" operator inconsistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80084/in-javascript-why-is-the-this-operator-inconsistent)

Comment: Sorry, this code is running inside nodejs interpreter, not the browser. I would never suppose there are any differences between these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Inside main scope of nodejs modules `this` variable refers to `module.exports` and by default it is equal to empty object `{}`**, you can prove it this by running these tree line

```
console.log(this === module.exports);
module.exports.a = "a";
console.log(this);
```

and output should be

```
true
{ a: 'a' }
```

This is why you get empty object in second call

---

But **inside a function in your module, `this` variable refers to `global` variable of nodejs**, to prove it create a module like below and run it

```
global.bar = "baz";
function foo() {
    console.log(this === global);
    console.log(global.bar);
}
foo();
```

and output should be

```
true
baz
```

And this is why you get right object in your first call

Answer (score 0):

Bind function in javascript is to change the context to which "this" points to.

If you want to "this" in echo function to dog object that you have created, you should pass dog as the argument to bind.

dog.echo =  echo.bind(dog);

Above line of code, change what "this" points in the echo function. So now it will point to the dog.

Here is the initial result of your code:
[image]

In both cases "this" in echo pointed to global object.

Now here result once you provide dog as an argument to bind. 
As you can see "this" changed for the second console.log. It pointed to dog object.
 [image]

Javascript should behave in some way in the browser and on the server side (most of the time). Node is built on top of javascript. It uses the same v8 engine to compile the javascript code.